# My code reaches a loop then stops working

Tags: java

I'm not sure why, but the code stops when it reaches the loop portion. I waited for 10 minutes...but still, absolutely nothing changed. It's not an infinite loop.

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File("CollectingTheData.txt"));
File dataCollection = new File("CollectingTheData.txt");
Scanner inF = new Scanner(dataCollection);

System.out.println("\nSimulating Trials Now...One Moment Please...");

RandomSquirels = (int)(Math.random() * 11 + 1);

while (RunCount <= TrialNumber) {
    while (RandomSquirels != 10) {
        out.println(RandomSquirels);
    }
    
    out.close();
    RunCount++;
}

while (inF.hasNextLine()) {
    NumRead = Integer.parseInt(inF.nextLine());
    SquirelTotal += NumRead;
    
}
inF.close();

CalculationsForAv = (double)SquirelTotal / (double)TrialNumber;

System.out.println("The results! \nThe Average Number of \nSquirels Observed until Observing a Fox Squirrel: " + CalculationsForAv);
```

I only included the relevant portion of code. Everything necessary is imported and all the variables are defined.

Comment: `out.close();`  - why?  If you close it here, then it will be closed for the next iteration of your outer while loop.

Comment: If you don't change the value of `RandomSquirels` in the loop, it **is** an infinite loop.

Comment: @sarahzboun If the answer below solves you problem please accept.

Comment: Java naming conventions have classes start with a capital letter; methods and variables start with a lower case letter (randomSquirels).

Comment: And yes, your code does contain an infinite loop -- ``while (RandomSquirels != 10) { }``. You don't change the value of RndomSquirels inside the loop, so it will never close. You didn't even remark on the fact that the print statement there kept printing the same number eternally.

Answer (score 2):

```
while (RandomSquirels != 10) {
    out.println(RandomSquirels);
}
```

You never change `RandomSquirels` value inside the while, I guess that what you wanted to do is:

```
while (RandomSquirels != 10) {
    out.println(RandomSquirels);
    RandomSquirels = (int)(Math.random() * 11 + 1);
}
```

I also noticed that you run `out.close()` inside a while, so you will try to close it over and over again... You shouldn't close a stream more then once.

Comment: But I already defined RandomSquirels? I just need it to keep printing random values until 10 comes up

Comment: @sarahzboun You defined it once, lets say that when you defined it you get '4' for example... But now `RandomSquirels` is equal to 4, and just print it will not change this. If you want to get a new random number you need to re-assign `RandomSquirels` with a new random number, like I did in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Java is an imperative language. You appear to think that this:

```
RandomSquirels = (int)(Math.random() * 11 + 1);
```

is like a macro, you think it means: "Everytime I write `RandomSquirels`, assume I wrote `(int)(Math.random() * 11 + 1)`. **That is not how java works**.

It means: Run the expression `(int)(Math.random() * 11 + 1)` right now, once, and assign the result of this to the variable `RandomSquirels`.

You then loop while `RandomSquirels` is not 10 and print it to the file. Forever, except once in every 11 runs, when the value so happens to resolve to 10.